# How to create a flat progress bar in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I am using Java FXML.

The progress bars look like this:
[JavaFX Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxMUN.png)

How do I remove the grey border around, but maintain the background.

To look like this:
[Desired Progress Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN54f.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a stylesheet and do this:

```
.progress-bar > .bar, .progress-bar > .track {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

You can do your own research from [CSS Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#progressbar) and [Modena Theme CSS](https://gist.github.com/maxd/63691840fc372f22f470) if you have similar problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, flat progress bar working with following style sheet

```
 .progress-bar > .bar {
    -fx-padding:0;
    -fx-background-radius:0;
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color: black;
}

.progress-bar > .track {
   -fx-background-color: lightgray, white;
   -fx-background-radius:0;
   -fx-background-insets: 0, 1;

}
```